# Post Image Array with Retroft Library

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to do a post of an image array with retrofit. I wrote the interface method as follow:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/rest/sendphotoprod")
DefaultResponseJson sendProductPicture(@Part("usekey") String usekey, @Part("images") List<TypedFile> pictures);
```

but the server is receiving something like:

```
{
    "usekey": "d64f4dc02b7b982ae7ff23802184f5ac",
    "images": "[{\"file\":{\"path\":\"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/1396300813071.jpeg\"},\"mimeType\":\"application/octet-stream\"}]"
}
```

I'm using retrofit version 1.5.0.